# How to convert a mobile application to APK using Nativescript step by step?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, apk, nativescript

Please, I have a project in this url: `C:\project\MyProjektMobileSecurity`

How to convert this project to apk file?

I look this `tns build android --release --key-store-path <path-to-your-keystore> --key-store-password <your-key-store-password> --key-store-alias <your-alias-name> --key-store-alias-password <your-alias-password> --copy-to <apk-location>.apk`

But I can't understand how? I want only to convert, not upload in playstore.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app by `tns run android` , you can find debug-apk in your **app-name/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/** directory.
I think you checked publish docs and you can see release apk directory info there. NS creates them on same directory(if you prepared release: release.apk, if not: debug.apk)